# ctime() method how to print the hours and seconds?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

HI,

I have the following code:

```
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;

  time ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "The current local time is: %s", ctime (&rawtime) );

  std::string datetoString(ctime (&rawtime) );
  return 0;
}

std::string datetoString (char dat[]) 
                     //how to add ctime(&rawtime) in char dat[]?
{
    std::string rez;
    struct tm;
    strptime(dat, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
        // what library do i have to inclide for strptime?

    rez=tm.tm_mday + "-" + tm.tm_mon +"-"+ tm.tm_year+ hour+min+sec;
                                //how to print the hour,minutes and secods?

return rez;
}
```

i have errors in the places where i've commented my questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localtime() to convert a time_t (seconds since the epoch) to a broken-down struct tm instance (or rather, localtime_r which is thread-safe). Finally, use strftime() to do string formatting. (No need to use ctime anywhere). E.g.

```
#include <time.h>

...
time (&rawtime);
struct tm foo;
struct tm *mytm;
mytm = localtime_r (&rawtime, &foo);
char outstr[200];
strftime(outstr, sizeof(outstr), "%H:%M:%S", mytm);
...
```

Error handling, fixing potential (trivial) bugs, conversion to std::string etc. left as an exercise for the reader.